# How to get index of node in number of nodes with special attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

xml:

```
<fields>
  <field name="name1" />
  <field name="special" />
  <field name="name1" />
  <field name="special" />
  <field name="name1" />
</fields>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:apply-temlates select="//field" />
```

...

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='special']">
  <xsl:value-of select="_what_here?_" />
</xsl:template>
```

My template must return 1 and 2 instead of 2 and 4 like position() do.
How can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `preceding-sibling::` axis instead to count all relevant `field` elements.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/fields">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field[@name='special']">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::field[@name='special']) + 1" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
12
```

---

Another solution is not to use a separate template at all, but a `for-each`. Inside `for-each`, the `position()` function behaves exactly as you'd like it to - it retrieves the position in the sequence of elements in `for-each`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/fields">
      <xsl:for-each select="field[@name='special']">
          <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```